# Unknown number of columns to create PredictionEngine in ML.NET

Tags: vb.net, machine-learning, ml.net

I have been writing a program to create custom Models for Machine Learning.
The user will read a .csv or .txt and pass that data to a DatagridView.

The DataGridView contains the columns "A", "B" and "C" (apart from "Label" column, which is the result), I created a model inserting all that columns in a `List (of string)` and concatenate then like this:(lista2 -> "A","B","C" / Lista value -> "Label")

```
 Dim estimator = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", lista2.ToArray) _
        .Append(mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.FastTree(labelColumnName:=Lista(Lista.Count - 1), featureColumnName:="Features"))
```

After that, I have 2 classes named NewData and NewDataPrediction with the following properties:

```
Public Class NewData

<LoadColumn(0)>
Public A As Single
<LoadColumn(1)>
Public B As Single
<LoadColumn(2)>
Public C As Single
<LoadColumn(3)>
Public Label As Boolean


Public Class NewDataPrediction
Inherits NewData

<ColumnName("PredictedLabel")>
Public Property Prediction As Boolean
Public Property Probability As Single
Public Property Score As Single
```

After this, I create the PredictionEngine

```
 Dim predictionFunction As PredictionEngine(Of NewData, NewDataPrediction) = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine(Of NewData, NewDataPrediction)(model)
```

The model is created with no problem and if I assign some values, It predictes everything right.

The problem is the following, Since the program reads the Text File, it can contain a different number of Columns with different names. How can I create the PredictionEngineModel with NewData(where I would like to insert all new columns, in an array,list or something and read the columns inside that list as properties in the class), since I cant create a class with properties at runtime. How can I approach this problem? Thanks